# Laravel Eloquent - update() function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel's Eloquent `update()` function returns a boolean, and not the updated entry. I'm using:

```
return User::find($id)->update( Input::all() )
```

And this returns only a boolean. Is there a way I can get the actual row, without running another query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's the behaviour that you want:

```
$user = User::find($id)->fill(Input::all());
return ($user->update())?$user:false;
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: You sir are a saviour! Is there a way to use `fill()` by passing the relationship data as well and then use `push()` to update all?

Comment: I had changes on the base `Model` class, and I made a kind of preprocess the Input before save/update. I split the related input data and save/update it all too inside the same transaction, but Eloquent doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Okay, so that in the case, I'll do something similar

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can is to use the laravel `tap` helper function.

Here is an example to use it for updating and getting the updated model:

```
$user = User::first();
$updated = tap($user)->update([
    "username" => "newUserName123"
]);
```

`tap($user)` allows us to chain any method from that model. While at the end, it will return the `$user` model instead of what `update` method returned.